# Openshift (curl): Get access to master API from a container

Tags: curl, openshift

I'm trying to get access to:

```
$ curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
    "https://openshift.default.svc.cluster.local/oapi/v1/users/~" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

I'm performing this command line from inside a terminal container, and I'm getting this message:

> curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

Comment: Use ``-k`` option to ``curl``. See http://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-do-i-enable-rest-api-access-for-an-application.html

Answer (score 0):

What have worked for me is the external, public URL of the master.